# Built app for iOS8 Using XCode 6, text still blurry on iPhone 6

Tags: ios8, xcode6

I am working on updating an app for `iOS8` and when building in XCode 6 and installing on my iPhone 6, the text throughout the app is still blurry. The status bar is also blurry.

What have I missed? Were there other steps that need to be taken?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add the correct sized launch images for the 6/6+. To do so you need to use an asset catalog for your launch images. (If you aren't clicking use asset catalog will prompt you to migrate) In the asset catalog select the launch image set, open the inspector and be sure iOS 8 is checked. You'll see the new image size slots. Clicking a slot will show you the required size in the inspector.

Comment: Wow. I never even realized that was there! I have been hesitant to use Asset Catalogs. No longer! Thanks!